# Python: draw different text in different 3d area with blf

Tags: python

The workspace has two 3d view areas.I want to draw one text on the top right corner of each 3d area to distinguish which area is right or left.But now I draw the same text.How can I solve this problem?[image]
here are my simple code:

```
def draw_right(self,text):
    """Draw on the viewports"""
    # BLF drawing routine
    override = getOverride()
    region = override['region']
    font_id = font_info["font_id"]
    blf.color(0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    blf.position(font_id, region.width - 100, region.height -100, 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 50)
    blf.draw(font_id, text)

font_info = {
    "font_id": 0,
    "handler": None,
}
bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_right, (None, 'L'), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```